# store formatted text in mysql using cakephp and angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, mysql, angularjs, cakephp

Currently i am trying to build an community page in which user can contribute there articles in well text format. My backend is cakephp and front-end is angular-js 
How can i store text in well formatted html style for example input text which i want to store in Mysql is

```
<b> hello </b><br/>
<em>world </em>
```

and when i fetch text from table output must be like

**hello**

*world*

update:-

and it should also work for inline CSS if it is possible then it is great.

```
<div style="color:#D2691E">hiiii</div>
```

i don't need to implement fancy animation-css tag but it should support basic css.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) directive, but before you must include the [$sanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize) service and put `ngSanitize` as a dependency of your application module.

Also implemented a `trusted` filter with the use of [$sce](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.23/docs/api/ng/service/$sce) which is a service that provides Strict Contextual Escaping services to AngularJS.

Strict Contextual Escaping (SCE) is a mode in which AngularJS requires bindings in certain contexts to result in a value that is marked as safe to use for that context.

Code:

```js
angular
  .module('myApp', ['ngSanitize'])
  .filter('trusted', ['$sce', function($sce) {
    return function(str) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(str);
    };
  }])
  .controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.myHTML = '<b>hello</b><br/><em>world</em>';
    $scope.myHTMLStyled = '<div style="color: #D2691E">hiiii</div>';
  });
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div ng-bind-html="myHTML"></div>
  <div ng-bind-html="myHTMLStyled | trusted"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i think you misunderstood my question. i made changes in my question so you can understand my problem. btw thank you for your time.